# POSTGRES SQL query to find all the rows which have one column contains number with format like 11 digits - 4 digits

Tags: sql, regex, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to write one postgress sql query , here i want to select all the rows , for which one column must contains string of below format , i am not able to construct regular expression for postgress , as am new to this DB

one column contains a string like   PRF:12345678901-1234  like this column values are present , so write a sql query to select all rows which have column value in this format , here PRF:  is constant it will never change the only changing value is that string after : symbol , can someone please help me in this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_column ~ '^[A-Z]{3}:\d{11}-\d{4}$';`

`~` tilde is used for regex evaluation and you can evaluate that the expression matches your needs [here](http://regexr.com/)

Comment: @eorge Daramouskas , thanks for the solution it worked . i have one more doubt , what if the column contains pure json , instead of line of text , because i tried this on one more column which is storing json , any idea please

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> ~ 'PRF:\d{11}-\d{4}'
```

Here is a [demo](http://rextester.com/WIWXH29610)